why do I need to use sudo to add my git username and git email name in the configuration when I am in a system directory
This is the sequel to this question: how put my /etc/nixos/configuration.nix on github
I was in a system directly.
In /etc/nixos but I think you can try with another one if you don t have nixos
I also had to launch this command before
    git config --global --add safe.directory /etc/nixos

(of course change /etc/nixos with another system directory)
it was needed to enter this command, when I wanted to make my first commit:
 git config --global user.email "myemail@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "MY Name"

otherwise
git commit -m "first commit"

Author identity unknown
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
git config --global user.email "you@example.com" git config --global
user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the
identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@nixos.(none)')

what i did. I looked fine
git config --list  show me the names and email have been added
But when I tried again
 git commit -m "first commit"

it had the same error message
I had to use sudo before my command.
I don t understand why it was necessary. because the command
 git config --list

printed the right email and name

"It didn't work"; why not? What error did you get? Does your non-root user has access to that folder/file?

I'd expect the git init to already fail if your regular user doesn't have write permissions to /etc/nixos.

@Ostone0 I ve added the error message now

@Robert git init works because of this command     git config --global --add safe.directory /etc/nixos

git config commands work on a per-user basis. If you run with sudo, you get their output for root, otherwise for your current user. So you need to repeat any setup steps with sudo, or e.g., cp ~/.gitconfig ~root/ to copy the settings. It does not matter if you work in a system directory. You need sudo in system directories because usually only root can write in them.

@Robert OK i ve understood Thanks
